# Cross site Scripting(XSS) Vulnerability possible

Tags: security, jscript, web-testing

My website doesn't have a search input but it has hyperlinks to other sites should I worry about XSS(cross site scripting) vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only link to websites that are secure and trusted. An example of a trusted website is one that uses https or one which is ranked high in Google.

If you link to an untrusted website, then its possible that when your visitors click on the link to the untrusted website, they are taken to a malicious website that serves malware or steals user credentials.

Comment: all  my hyperlinks are trusworthy.So there would be no XSS issues right?

Comment: Well if your hyperlinks are stored in database, then it is possible for a hacker to change them using sql injection. So all data that is fetched from database should be filtered

Comment: I don't have any database .hope that XSS is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

XSS can be not only in search input field =). Any input, which your web application outputs and does not perform filtration leads to XSS. If you have outdated JS libraries (e.g. old version of jQuery) - it can also contain vulnerable code and lead to XSS.

Comment: I agree. Data that is fetched from database and displayed to user can contain malicious code. For example a hacker can inject malicious code into a database using SQL injection

Comment: @Nadir With HTTP POST request, as part of the URL, or with the web browser cookie is it possible? (in my website)

Comment: @ajithkumar Yes it is possible to inject malicious code into a website through HTTP Post variables or HTTP Get variables. So you should sanitize all input of your application before processing it.

Comment: Could it be resolved by disabling the POST request on the server(we are using IIS server)

Comment: How to sanitize all input of my application before processing it ?